# A sequence in base 3

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Take the sequence of numbers such that no two of them average to another:
$$   0, 1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 12, 13, 27, 28, 30, 31, 36, 37, 39, 40,\ldots$$
I've discovered through experimentation that if we set the first two terms to $0$ and $1$, the rest of them can be found through the observation that if $n$ is in the sequence, so is $3n$ and $3n+1$.
I don't know how to prove it, though. I'm not even really sure where to start.

How can I prove this?

Comment: It's described in https://oeis.org/A005836 as "Numbers n whose base 3 representation contains no 2". I don't know how to prove that this is the same sequence, but the references in that page should provide plenty of breadcrumbs.

Comment: Um,  if you leave 3n out the rest still won't average to anything else.  Are you requiring that everything that can be in must be in?

Comment: @fleablood Sorry, yes, I should have clarified. Everything that can be in needs to be. Thanks!

Comment: What if you specify the base 3 digits as 0 and 2?  That also works; all members are then twice those given here. But using base 3 digits of 1 and 2 does not (1,2,4,5,7,... where 4 is the average of 1 and 7).  What enters in the last case?  Note that when you have two numbers with a power of 3 between them, like 1 and 7 with 3 between them, a "hidden" leading zero from the smaller number gets into the averaging and messes up the binary string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [sequence A005836](http://oeis.org/A005836) in the OEIS.

A characterization equivalent to the one you've found experimentally is that when written in base $3$, this sequence is $$0_3, 1_3, 10_3, 11_3, 100_3, 101_3, 110_3, 111_3, 1000_3, 1001_3, \dots$$
and consists precisely of the numbers whose base-$3$ representation does not use the digit $2$. (Going from $n$ to $3n$ and $3n+1$ is the same as adding a $0$ or $1$ to the end of the base-$3$ representation; that's why this is equivalent.)

This sequence does not contain a triple $(a,b,c)$ with $b = \frac{a+c}{2}$ or equivalently $2b = a+c$. If it did, note that $a+c$ can be computed without carrying in base $3$, and at some point where the digits of $a$ and $c$ disagree, we get the digit $1$ in the sum. On the other hand, all the digits of $2b$ are $2$ or $0$, so $2b$ cannot be equal to $a+c$.

It's slightly trickier to prove that this is the sequence we get by going through the integers in order and always adding an element if it can be added without creating a pair $(a,b,c)$ with $b = \frac{a+c}{2}$. By the above argument, we know that, as long as we've never added anything not in the sequence above, its next element can always be added. How do we know that we'll never add a number not in the sequence: whose base $3$ representation does contain a $2$?

I will prove this by example, because otherwise I'd have to make up messy notation, but this argument is fully general. Suppose that we're considering adding the number $x = 1021201_3$, and that *so far* we've not deviated from the sequence above. Define $$\begin{cases}x_{2\to 1} = 1011101_3 \\ x_{2\to 0} = 1001001_3\end{cases}$$ to be the two numbers we get by replacing every $2$ with a $1$ and a $0$ respectively. Then $x_{2\to 1}$ and $x_{2\to0}$ are both smaller than $x$, and neither contains a $2$, so both are in the sequence. But we have $$x_{2\to 1} = \frac{x_{2\to 0} + x}{2}$$ so we can't add $x$.

Note also that this sequence is not actually the *densest* sequence that has this property. In this sequence, among the first $3^n$ terms, we've chosen $2^n$, so among the first $N$ we choose an average of $N^{\log_3 2}$. But we can get better constructions by *not* picking greedily, which contain more than $N^{1-\epsilon}$  of the first $N$ positive integers for any $\epsilon>0$. The most well-known is [Behrend's construction](http://www.epsilonsmall.com/resources/behrends-construction/behrend.pdf), which chooses $$N \cdot e^{- O(\sqrt{\log N})}$$ of the first $N$ positive integers.

Comment: Why are the digits of $2b$ either $0$ or $2$?

Comment: If you multiply a number like $1110101_3$ by $2$, you get $2220202_3$. In other words, you just multiply every digit by $2$, and don't have to carry.

Comment: Oh of course! Sorry, my brain just stopped working. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much. This sure is interesting...

Comment: Among the first $N$ whole numbers the given sequence chooses approximately $N^{log_3 2}$.  The exponent had been mistyped as $log_2 3$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Is there a way to find out total number of terms upto a given limit $N$?

Comment: @striker Write $N$ in base $3$, if necessary rounding down to the nearest number with no $2$s in the representation (taking the leftmost $2$ and replacing $2xxxx\dots$ by $11111\dots$). Then number of sequence terms below $N$ is the number of integers below that number read in base $2$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks, I really appreciate it if you can give me a small example.

Comment: @striker Say $N = 96 = 10120_3$. Round that down to $10111_3$: the highest number below $N$ that can appear in the sequence. Read that as $10111_2 = 22$. Then the number of sequence terms below $N$ is equal to the number of *nonnegative* (sorry, I left that out in the previous comment) integers below $22$: they are $0, 1, 2, \dots, 22$ so there's $23$ of them.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks :)

Comment: @MishaLavrov One more question, why? means why the number of sequence terms below $N$ is the number of integers below that number read in base $2$

Comment: Because the terms in the sequence before $10111_3$ are just $0_3, 1_3, 10_3, 11_3, 100_3, 101_3, 110_3, 111_3, \dots, 10110_3, 10111_3$. If you read these in base $2$ instead, you get $0_2, 1_2, 10_2, 11_2, \dots, 10110_2, 10111_2$ which are just all the consecutive numbers $0, 1, 2, 3, \dots, 21, 22$. (By the way, all this would have been better done by asking a separate question and linking to it here, since answering questions in actual answer posts is easier.)